# While compiling the code....: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.**

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit **value 1**
```

Comment: Can you give some more information?

Answer (score 0):

You added too much dependencies in your project, to solve follow these steps:

```
defaultConfig {
 ...
 multiDexEnabled true
 ...
}
```

and

```
dexOptions {
    jumboMode = true
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

in your `build.gradle` app module file.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file add

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        .... />
```

That should solve the problem.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Can you upload your dependencies {} part of build.gradle?

Comment: packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.0-alpha3'
}